# Create a node only if misses in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I as far as i know i can do this with cypher with th `CREATE UNIQUE` command as described [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.7/query-create-unique.html#create-unique-create-nodes-with-values). But in this way I will connect all my nodes with the source node which i think is unnecessary. Is there another way to create a node if misses? Do i have performance penalties?

I am familiar with `MERGE` command introduced in neo4j 2.0 but my application but my code is build with JKD 1.6 so i can't use it and I have to stick to neo4j 1.9.7

Answer (score 0):

You could use Neo4j server if you're using Cypher anyway, then you're independent of the server's Java-version and you can upgrade it to 2.x

Otherwise there is no way in Cypher in 1.9.x but you if you use java, have a look at the "Unique Node Creation" section of the manual:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.7/transactions-unique-nodes.html